# React.PureComponent renders all the items in a list component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We have created a re-usable list component using ReactJS. However, due to performance issues, we decided to implement - **shouldComponentUpdate** method with the conditions on when should my list component render

```
public shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: TreeItemInternalProps, nextState: {}): boolean {
  if (this.props.treeObject.selected !== nextProps.treeObject.selected) {
    return true;
  }
  if (this.props.treeObject.expanded !== nextProps.treeObject.expanded) {
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

Meaning, I wanted to render my component only when the value of the checkbox of list item changes.

Let's say, due to some reason, I can't do this anymore. Now, my alternatives are using PureComponent which does a shallow compare. So, it should render only the list item which changed. However, even using after using the PureComponent, the entire component is getting rendered.

To explain the scenario properly, see the following screenshots -

1. Without using PureComponent / using the conditional check in shouldComponentUpdate

[image]

Here, you can see the log "component is rendered" was called only once, meaning, only for the change I did in the prop (this is the same requirement, I want to implement using PureComponent)

---

2. With using PureComponent

[image]

Here, you can see the log "component is rendered" was called 3 times, even though I had changed just the props of first list item. This is using PureComponent

Comment: PureComponent does a `shallow` check against your props, for a deep comparison you might need to have the lifecycle.Read this: https://medium.com/@baphemot/note-that-purecomponent-does-a-shallow-comparison-of-props-so-if-you-use-complex-data-structures-8675023e0b92

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, PureComponent will render only when there is any change in the props or state. However, just React.Component renders every second. @Nicolae Maties

Comment: Yes that's true. You are either changing the props in the parent or the state . You need to share the code of the Component and its parent so that we can help you. Or create a codesandbox to reproduce the issue without your exact code.

Comment: @Domino987 allow me some time, I will revert back with either the code or if I am able to set up the sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PureComponent is always rendering for you because most likely your `Props` or `State` contain ANY objects or arrays that are being created in the parent component during the parent's re renders.

As others of said, it does a shallow comparison for re-renders (meaning an object reference won't equal a NEW object reference, even if they are DEEP equal), so the parent component is acting as a bottleneck to it's PureComponent child, as every re-render recreates a whole new object reference

If you REALLY wanted to use a PureComponent, you would have to simplify all the other props in your component to be primitives or objects/arrays that do not get a new reference on every re render of the parent

Example of problem:

```
class Todo extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>this.props.foo</div>;
  }
}

class MyTodoList extends Component {
 render () {
   const fooBar = {foo: 'bar'}
   return <Todo fooBar={fooBar} />
  }
}
```

Example of fix:

```
class Todo extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>this.props.foo</div>;
  }
}

class MyTodoList extends Component {
 render () {
   return <Todo fooBar={props.fooBar} />
  }
}
```

Probably the best thing you want to do is bring up that object creation as high as you can to a component that does NOT re render on these kind of changes, or simplify every single prop to a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

React.PureComponent does the shallow comparison on their props and states.
So changing the object property of the state or props won't re-render the component. 
We need to reconstruct the state or props only when the state or props in interests is changed.
For example, we can write the code as below to re-render only when forceRender flag is set.

```
class ShalloWCompareComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  }

  update() {
    const { forceRender } = this.props;
    const { userArray } = this.state;
    if (forceRender) {
      this.setState({
        userArray: [...userArray, 6]
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        userArray: userArray.push(6)
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <b>Array Length is: {this.state.userArray.length}</b>
  }
}
```

If this component receives the props of forceRender={false}, calling update() wouldn't re-render the component thanks to the shallow comparison of the React.PureComponent.